# Inconsistent OSF in Table of Contents using Microtype, LuaLaTeX and Tocstyle

Tags: table-of-contents, luatex, microtype, oldstylenums, tocstyle

My table of contents should have the following properties:

- oldstyle figures for page numbers and labels
- chapter entries in spaced, lowercase smallcaps
- numbers close (en-space) to the entries, no dotfill

You should be able to see in the MWE that oldstyle figures are produced for all labels and the page-numbers of the sections, *but not for the page numbers of the chapters*.

The oldstyle figures appear, if I comment either the

- `lsstyle` command or the
- `\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn}`

Both indicated in the MWE. As shown in the MWE-chapter Introduction, the combination (`lsstyle`, `scshape`, `lowercase`) works in normal text and produces oldstyle figures.

Please note

- there are some problems when setting letterspaced smallcaps with LuaLaTeX. This is why I use the setting `\addfontfeature{Renderer=Basic}`.)
- you need Microtype2.5 to reproduce the problem
- the problem may be related to [this tex.SE entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89509/conflict-between-microtype-lualatex-and-otf-fonts-when-typesetting-material-in)

MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[letterspace=70]{microtype}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Myriad Pro}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{nopagecolumn} % comment this to see OSF
\settocfeature[toc][0]{entryhook}{\scshape\addfontfeature{Renderer=Basic}
\lsstyle % comment this to see OSF
\lowercase}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

% to show that the combination works in normal text
{\scshape\addfontfeature{Renderer=Basic}\lsstyle\lowercase{aBcDeF 1234567890}}

\chapter{Methods}
\section{Method A}
\section{Method B}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `\settocfeature[toc][0]{pagenumberhook}{}` all page numbers are oldstyle.

Comment: The empty argument was the trick. I already tried `\normalfont` and `\addfontfeature{Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}}` as `pagenumberhook`. Still a very weird problem, isn't it? Can you comment why this solution works?

Comment: Sorry, but I tried once to understand `tocstyle` and gave up.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug, I don’t know, but the package itself prints out a warning on every run, that it is in alpha state.