# microtype tracking disables small caps in luaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, small-caps, microtype

Normall `microtype` tracking loosens the tracking of small caps. However, with `fontspec`'s `\setmainfont{`ebgaramond`}`, small caps are completely disabled and I get a loose normal text,

[image]

as opposed to

[image]

with the corresponding font package and normal pdfLaTeX. I want to use LuaLaTeX for some fancy ligatures, and XeLaTeX messes everything up.

Using the `ebgaramond` package in LuaLaTeX doesn't help.

Comment: `microtype` doesn't go well with luaLaTeX.

Comment: @HarishKumar Is there a way to loose-track small caps outside of `\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}` but while not interfering with `microtype`'s other duties? In other words, can I achieve this effect while keeping `microtype` for my other stuff?

Comment: There is beta version of microtype but I am not sure as to what extent it is good. I don't have much experience with lua. Let us wait for luatexperts :-)

Comment: You need to load the font with `Renderer=Basic` (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27625/7674)). The upcoming version of `microtype` will also work with the `Full` renderer.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89509/7674) is also the same problem. Duplicate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you provide the instruction

```
\defaultfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}
```

then the `tracking` option of the `microtype` package seems to work correctly:

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Christianity} Christianity
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not using tracking in the example.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks for pointing this out. Adding the instruction `\defaultfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}}` seems to do the job if tracking is enabled. I'll update my example accordingly.