# Combine kerning, small caps, and tracking in luatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype, kerning, luaotfload

[As is known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132887/9077), `luatex` requires the `fontspec` option `Renderer = Basic` in order to display small caps when `microtype`'s `tracking = true` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tracking = true]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertine Serif}[%
    SmallCapsFeatures = {%
%       Renderer = Basic, % breaks kerning, but allows small caps
        Letters = SmallCaps}]
\begin{document}
\textsc{ipa}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*With* `Renderer = Basic`, however, proper kerning between the characters `P` and `A` is removed:

[image]

@KhaledHosny [tells me](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertine/issues/3) that this is because "Libertine uses class based kerning, which does not seem to be supported by the base mode of luaotfload". I'm curious to find out if there's a way to work around this problem?

The following screen capture from FontForge shows that there's supposed to be a `-25` kerning between small caps `P` and `A` (click on the picture for a full size version).

[image]

As a test, I've tried to increase the kerning from `-25` to `-80`, but the output with `luatex` is unchanged.

Comment: Is a kern defined between small caps p and a to begin with?

Comment: @egreg Yes. One second, and I'll add a (unfortunately huge) screen capture.

Comment: Might "Libertine Serif" also be called "Linux Libertine O"? Or is it an entirely different font?

Comment: @Mico [`libertine`](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertine) is a fork of `linux libertine` provided by @KhaledHosny

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the LetterSpace option in `fontspec`. It preserves kerning as you can see if you compare it with the output of Renderer=basic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine_R}[%
    Extension = .otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures = {%
    LetterSpace = 10,
    Letters = SmallCaps}]
\setsansfont{LinLibertine_R}[%
    Extension = .otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures = {%
    LetterSpace = 10,
    Renderer = Basic,
    Letters = SmallCaps}]    
\begin{document}
\textsc{ipav} \par \sffamily \textsc{ipav}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While the `letterspace` value in `microtype` is given in thousandths of 1em (see the manual under 3.4), the `letterspace` value in `luaotfload` is given as a percentage of the font size (see the manual under 4.1). That can be a source of confusion. So if I understand it correctly `letterspace = 100` in `microtype` should be identical to `letterspace = 10` in `luaotfload`.

Comment: It turns out that it's sufficient to use `fontspec`'s `LetterSpace` option, and this works for both lualatex and xelatex. So I've edited your answer accordingly, if you don't mind.

Comment: Letterspace is not the same than kerning.  Letterspace uses the same spacing for all letters, on the other hand kerning uses the best spacing for every pair of letters.

Comment: @skan: that's exactly what my example shows: the letterspacing between all letters and the kerning between AV.